# How to call the Manage Map Cache Tiles tool hosted by default in the system folder of arcgis server. I am getting ERROR 001428

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, arcpy

When I am trying to call the GP tool Manage map service cache tiles that is hosted on the arcgis server by default in the system folder, I am geeting the followning error:
ERROR 001428 Failed to retrieve configuration for service .

Here is the message of the call I am trying to perform:
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing (Manage Map Cache Tiles): ManageMapCacheTiles http://go-infra.eurodyn.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/OSCAR/OSCAR_GO_NMI_Cached_service_program_All/MapServer 591657527,591555;295828763,795777;147914381,897889;73957190,948944;36978595,474472;18489297,737236;9244648,868618;4622324,434309;2311162,217155 3 RECREATE_ALL_TILES # # "Feature Set"

and here the complete error message:
esriJobMessageTypeError: ERROR 001428: Failed to retrieve configuration for service http://go-infra.eurodyn.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/OSCAR/OSCAR_GO_NMI_Cached_service_program_All/MapServer.
esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed to execute (Manage Map Cache Tiles).
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Failed at Wed May 27 19:34:16 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,16 seconds)
esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use periods instead of commas in the arcpy script to denote decimal places in your scale range.